# Javascript + CSS issues. Can't modify style

Tags: javascript

I am editing a javascript Jeopardy game for an activity (mostly styling). However one of the things 
I changed was how many players are allowed and now they overlap out of the box when you click on an answer.

game: http://warp.byu.edu/jeopardy/

see image below:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/jeopardy.png/

My issue is that all my changes to CSS dont make a difference. I think the JS is setting the width ( i couldnt make anything work).

any ideas?

Comment: How would you like it to look instead?

Comment: Time to learn about Firebug...

Comment: can you be a little more specific in what you're doing? how are you adding CSS? did you link it? are you using javascript to add it? if so, can we see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a max-width on the css and it won't go past that

Comment: That worked. I tried it before and for some reason the change wasnt being reflected in browser. PC restart fixed that. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Vote up please.